# Groupby and find common string part starting from left in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a test data from [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/x6m3q0xlx9brsmi67ns7v/test_data.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=jaht6ycnj2c1vlteojtoc56rx):

[image]

I would like to groupby `poi` column and select 2 rows for each group, then find `common address` part (**the colored part from table above**) for each group starting from left, ie., `ceng` are common for `poi` is `1`, but it has been ignored.

For filter rows which has at least 2 rows for `poi` and select 2 rows for each group.

```
df = df[df['poi'].duplicated(keep=False)]
df.groupby('poi').head(2).reset_index(drop=True)
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to do that in Pandas or other Python packages? Thanks.

The expected result:

```
   poi                                         common_address
0    1  Jian Guo Lu 81hao Hua Mao Zhong Xin Xie Zi Lou Yi Zuo
1    3          JiNan - ShiZhong District, Shandong, 5hao Lou
2    4                     Shang Hai Shi Tian Shan Lu 1825hao
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A custom aggregation function solves it. For the example above, I suggest the following:

```
from typing import Optional

def agg_func(data: pd.DataFrame) -> Optional[str]:
    if data.shape[0] < 2:
        return None

    return common_prefix(data.address.iloc[0], data.address.iloc[1])

def common_prefix(str1: str, str2: str) -> Optional[str]:
    i = 0
    to_keep = 0
    while i < len(str1) and i < len(str2) and str1[i] == str2[i]:
        # the common part of address should not end on a digit part or a space
        if str1[i].isalpha():
            to_keep = i
        i += 1
    
    return str1[:to_keep+1].strip()


ans = df[["poi", "address"]].groupby(["poi"]).agg(agg_func).dropna(axis=0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I try this code to a new data, it raises an error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iloc'`, could you help pls?

Comment: I tried to see what the error is, but I don't see it. Just double-checking: it's the line with `return common_prefix(data.address.iloc[0], data.address.iloc[1])` that raises, right? Sorry for not being helpful.

Comment: No problem, maybe change to `return common_prefix(data.address[0], data.address[1])`?

Comment: If really needed, we can convert series to list by applying `data.values[0]`, but for the latest pandas, `iloc` should be the most appropriate method to access the field.